# time complexity for the given recursive equation

Tags: performance, recursion, big-o, time-complexity

Hi can i know what would be the Big Oh time complexity for the given recursive equation
T(N) = 2T(N/2) + 2
and can any one suggest any materials to lean time complexity of recursive algorithms .
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It's <del>`O(nlgn)`</del> **Edit:** `O(n)` since `+2` term clearly falls into first case of master theorem, as described in Cormen's [Introduction to Algorithms](http://emiraga.wikispaces.com/file/view/Introduction.to.Algorithms.3rd.Edition.Sep.2010.pdf), chapter I.4.5.

Comment: I think you are wrong , just now i figured it out , check this
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem#Application_to_common_algorithms
The answer is O(n)

Comment: I think you are right. After all those years I've forgotten difference between big-Oh and theta. I'll fix my answer.